# Python Break File Lines into List to Send to MySQL

Tags: php, python, mysql, list

I have a file that is created with Python and I want to send the information in it to a database. I'm having trouble figuring out how I could accomplish this with Python instead of using a PHP script to finish this process. This is how I have it currently working with PHP....

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$file_handle = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
        $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
        $FIRST = $parts[0];
        $SECOND = $parts[1];
        $THIRD = $parts[2];

    $query = "INSERT INTO table (One, Two, Three)" .
            "VALUES ('$FIRST', '$SECOND', '$THIRD')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            or die('Error querying database.');
            }
    fclose($file_hadle);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

The file I want to work with is a text file that contains a bunch of lines that are all in this format

```
105a9afg0e8bc456egf9bc9852abcd78 00.1.1.2 Example
105a9afg0e8bc456egf9bc9852abcd78 00.1.1.2 Example2
```

I have the MySQLdb to handle connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo can try with:

```
  >>> File = open("Foo", "r")
  >>> for i in File.readlines(): print i.rstrip().split()
 ... 
 ['105a9afg0e8bc456egf9bc9852abcd78', '00.1.1.2', 'Example']
 ['105a9afg0e8bc456egf9bc9852abcd78', '00.1.1.2', 'Example2']
```

Comment: That is more of what I was looking for I believe.

Now what would be the best way using MySQLdb to send this to the database? Each line would be its own row in the database and each part of the line its own column.

Comment: use i.rstrip().split()[0] i.rstrip().split()[1] i.rstrip().split()[2] as values for the insert in mysql